# MATLAB: How to print shapes over an image without using the vision package

Tags: matlab

So, I have a list of points that I want to plot with small boxes around them over an image in MATLAB. The code I have is:

```
img = imread('my_img.jpg');
corners = rand(20, 3);
corners(:,1) = uint8(size(img, 1) * corners(:,1));
corners(:,2) = uint8(size(img, 2) * corners(:,2));

figure(); hold on;
imshow(img, []);
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
for i = 1:size(corners, 1)
    rectangle('Position', [corners(i, 1:2) - 4 corners(i, 1:2) + 4], 'EdgeColor' 'r');
end
hold off;
```

However, I get some weird parody of what I want. Most of the rectangles are not even on the image, and none of the centers are.

[image]
How do I make the rectangles center on the appropriate pixel in the image with width values also in pixels? Oh, and I can't use the vision package so no insertShapes =/.

**UPDATE:**
I was assuming that the four points on the rectangle represented the Cartesian coordinates of the lower-lefthand corner and the upper-righthand corner. Instead, the last two coordinates represented the size of the box. So, if I mod the rectangle line to be:

```
rectangle('Position', [corners(i,1:2) 4 4], 'EdgeColor', 'r');
```

And also change my `corners` variable so:

```
corners(:, 1) = size(img, 1) - corners(:, 1);
corners(:, 2) = size(img, 2) - corners(:, 2);
```

Now, I get:

[image]

This is closer, but when I examine the actual values of my `corners` object, I find that none of the boxes should be off the image. So, what's going on here?

Comment: Given that `corners` is almost certainly driving the behavior, you need to provide a [mcve], not tell us to assume some random array of values.

Comment: @excaza I have done so

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/sco1/f939a79cfe07668c109379cf2045b1b4) results in [this](http://i.imgur.com/cz7UK6X.png). So, again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You have x and y flipped. X is the second dimension. Also the second inputs to the rect position are the width and height NOT another position

Comment: @Suever Okay, that fixed it!

Comment: @Woody1193 You still have x and y flipped (notice the point laying outside of your image). It should be `corners(:, 2) = size(img, 1) - corners(:, 2);` Also the other one should be `corners(:, 1) = size(img, 2) - corners(:, 1);`